# Camelcase serialization of “FromRoute” request properties

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-2.1

In my ASP.NET Core 2.1 MVC application, I want to expose a route like this:

```
/address/v1/postcode/{postcode}/street/{street}
```

I have defined my controller like this:

```
[Route("address/v1")]
[ApiController]
public class StreetController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet("postcode/{postcode}/street/{street}")]
    public ActionResult<GetStreetDetailsResponse> GetStreetDetails([FromRoute] GetStreetDetailsRequest request)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class GetStreetDetailsRequest
{
    [Required]
    [StringLength(4, MinimumLength = 4)]
    [RegularExpression("^[\\d]+$")]
    public string Postcode { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Street { get; set; }
}

public class GetStreetDetailsResponse
{
}
```

The route resolves as expected, however, the framework is not deserializing the Postcode and Street values, and those properties are not populated correctly in GetStreetDetailsRequest.

For example, if I call:

http://localhost/address/v1/postcode/0629/street/whatever

when it gets into the action method, the value of request.Postcode="{postcode}" and request.Street="{street}".

The issue appears to be due to the casing of my property names, because if I change GetStreetDetailsRequest to:

```
public class GetStreetDetailsRequest
{
    [Required]
    [StringLength(4, MinimumLength = 4)]
    [RegularExpression("^[\\d]+$")]
    public string postcode { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string street { get; set; }
}
```

everything works correctly. However, I’m not happy with that solution as it doesn't follow conventional C# naming standards.

I’ve tried decorating the properties with [DataMember(Name="postcode")] or [JsonProperty("postcode")], but these seem to be ignored too.

For the record, in my Startup.ConfigureServices() method I am using the default serializer, which I understand supports camel case:

```
services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
```

Has anyone got a solution that will enable me to expose the route with camel case properties using Pascal case in the request object property names?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are correct in some way. This:

```
[HttpGet("postcode/{postcode}/street/{street}")]
```

Says you have a `postcode` and a `street` property, and you have none of them. If you want the default binding to work, the casing must match exactly:

```
[HttpGet("postcode/{Postcode}/street/{Street}")]
```

Comment: Thanks, yes, I should have said I had found [HttpGet("postcode/{Postcode}/street/{Street}")] worked too, but that does not give me the route documentation (camel case) that I want in the swagger documentation produced by swashbuckle.